# send_and_ping() in bitcoin core tests

Tags: bitcoin-core, functional-test

Is there any downside if send_and_ping() was a hidden RPC instead of just a function in python test framework?

```
    def send_and_ping(self, message, timeout=60):
        self.send_message(message)
        self.sync_with_ping(timeout=timeout)
```

```
    def send_message(self, message):
        """Send a P2P message over the socket.

        This method takes a P2P payload, builds the P2P header and adds
        the message to the send buffer to be sent over the socket."""
        tmsg = self.build_message(message)
        self._log_message("send", message)
        return self.send_raw_message(tmsg)
```

Comment: It sends a message via the P2P network; I don't see how it could be an RPC - it wouldn't be testing the same thing.

Comment: If an RPC for example `sendmessage` with `message` and `peer` as arguments would be implemented which sends messages to peer, we can remove this function and just use RPC in tests? This is my understanding which can be incorrect

Comment: I think you're confused about what this is testing. It's sending P2P messages directly to the node being tested, to see if it reacts correctly to them. You can't replace that with an RPC - the purpose is testing P2P behavior, not RPC behavior.

Comment: After thinking for sometime I understood the difference. It can't be a replacement but hidden RPC can be helpful maybe in some cases. Example: Sending message to other node using POST requests